# how to create fake reflections on objects?

Tags: materials, image, edit-mode

i am designing a logo for my local esports team.

this is what i have accomplished till now , learning from tutorials and ebooks
[image]

and i wanted to make it similar to 
[image]

this image.

as you can see by comparing the images , i am nowhere near that.
to get the something like a reflection, i UV mapped an image on to the letters it does look better but still looks bad

i want it to look as close as it can .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you have created your shape in Illustrator or whatever application you use for SVG.

[image: Logo]

You create a new scene in Blender, delete the cube and put the render engin to Cycles

[image: Select Cycles]

After, just import your svg file

[image: Import SVG]

You should have your tiny svg file appearing in the scene, select all parts that will have the same material (Shift + B) and join them

[image: Join parts]

Go to your material panel and click on use nodes

[image: Material panel]

To ease the process, change the viewport color to white

[image: Change viewport color]

We're ready to work on the extrusion and the bevel, so go to the curve panel and play with the settings to have something that suits you.

[image: Curve panel]

Now the material part, go to the node editor

[image: Node editor]

And add (Maj + A) a Glossy Shader, a Mix Shader connect everything as the image below

[image: Node setup]

Time to add some light, create 2 planes, that you'll place in order to have good reflections, you'll have to play a little bit with it so the render suits you

[image: Light setup]

The we are going to create the material for the planes, so go back to the node editor and create a Emission shader, set the strength to 15

[image: Emission node]

And last but not least, the glowing corner. Select the part that you didn't join during the first steps, and create a node setup as this one

[image: Glowing node]

Set the camera and hit render, you should get something like this:

[image: Z]

It is not perfect, but with some tryouts, and a little bit of compositing you should reach a good result.

Comment: i will try to add some lighting , and i havent imported the logo via SVG i have modeled it within blender . i want that metal kind of look , thanks for helping

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I'm writing down the process, but I think it will be easier for you if you import it in SVG

Comment: i imported it with svg and the imported image was for some reason pixelated so the flat sides and edges werent actually flat , it looked bad

Comment: Check the update, I'm writing the tutorial

Comment: so you used nodes to add the black thing which works like a reflection ... nice,thanks for helping . anyway i can get the black part to tilt?

Comment: Actually, with Cycles, the glossy shader acts like a mirror. So you get reflections. :) 

Hope it was useful